# Prisma.io equivalent of Mongoose isModified method

Tags: javascript, prisma

Just wondering if there is something in Prisma equivalent to the Mongoose isModified method
to be used in Prisma middleware

```
prisma.$use(async (params, next) => {

if (params.model == 'User' && params.action == 'create') {
   // check if password modified
    params.args.data.password = await bcrypt.hash(params.args.data.password, 10);

   }

   return next(params);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [findMany](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting) method

```
if (params.model == 'User' && params.action == 'create') {
  // check if password modified
  const result = await prisma.user.findMany({
    where: {
      email: email
    }
  })
  const receivedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(params.args.data.password)
  if (result[0].password === receivedPassword) {
    params.args.data.password = await bcrypt.hash(params.args.data.password, 10);
  }
}
```